# when we call persist on dataframe and specify storage level to be MEMORY_ONLY or MEMORY_ONLY_SER what is actually serialized/de-serialized?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, serialization

I was reading about tungsten engine in Spark and figured out when we use dataframe Spark internally create a compact binary format that represent data and apply transformation chain on that compact binary format. in the `Spark in Action` book `MEMORY_ONLY` and `MEMORY_ONLY_SER` are defined like this:

- `MEMORY_ONLY`:‌ This is the default level. It will store the RDD
  composing the dataframe as **deserialized** Java objects in the JVM. If
  the RDD does not fit in memory, Spark will not cache the partitions;
  Spark will recompute as needed. You will not be notified.
- `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`:‌ Similar to MEMORY_ONLY, but the Java objects are
  **serialized**. This should take less space, but reading will consume
  more CPU.

I write this simple program in order to test `persist()` functionality in dataframe:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("test persist")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate();
String filename = "data/numbers.csv";
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
          new StructField("value", DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty())});

Dataset<Row> df = spark
                      .read()
                      .schema(schema)
                      .option("header", false)
                      .csv(filename);
df = df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
df.count();
df = df.withColumn("value", col("value").plus(5))
        .withColumn("value", col("value").plus(6));

ExplainCommand explain = new ExplainCommand(df.queryExecution().logical(), ExplainMode.fromString("codegen"));
  for (InternalRow internalRow : spark.sessionState()
          .executePlan(explain)
          .executedPlan()
          .executeCollect()) {
      System.out.println(internalRow.getString(0));
  }
```

`numbers.csv` is a simple text file contains numbers:

```
1
2
2
3
4
5
6
6
7
```

first I set storage level to `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY()` then `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER()` and examine the generated code for both states, **THEY ARE THE SAME!**

for `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER()` the generated code is:

```
Generated code:
/* 001 */ public Object generate(Object[] references) {
/* 002 */   return new GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(references);
/* 003 */ }
/* 004 */
/* 005 */ // codegenStageId=1
/* 006 */ final class GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1 extends org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator {
/* 007 */   private Object[] references;
/* 008 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs;
/* 009 */   private int columnartorow_batchIdx_0;
/* 010 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2 = new org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector[1];
/* 011 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3 = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[2];
/* 012 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1 = new org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch[1];
/* 013 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0 = new scala.collection.Iterator[1];
/* 014 */
/* 015 */   public GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(Object[] references) {
/* 016 */     this.references = references;
/* 017 */   }
/* 018 */
/* 019 */   public void init(int index, scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs) {
/* 020 */     partitionIndex = index;
/* 021 */     this.inputs = inputs;
/* 022 */     columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0[0] = inputs[0];
/* 023 */
/* 024 */     columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[0] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 0);
/* 025 */     columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 0);
/* 026 */
/* 027 */   }
/* 028 */
/* 029 */   private void columnartorow_nextBatch_0() throws java.io.IOException {
/* 030 */     if (columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0[0].hasNext()) {
/* 031 */       columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] = (org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch)columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0[0].next();
/* 032 */       ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[1] /* numInputBatches */).add(1);
/* 033 */       ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[0] /* numOutputRows */).add(columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0].numRows());
/* 034 */       columnartorow_batchIdx_0 = 0;
/* 035 */       columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2[0] = (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector) columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0].column(0);
/* 036 */
/* 037 */     }
/* 038 */   }
/* 039 */
/* 040 */   protected void processNext() throws java.io.IOException {
/* 041 */     if (columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] == null) {
/* 042 */       columnartorow_nextBatch_0();
/* 043 */     }
/* 044 */     while ( columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] != null) {
/* 045 */       int columnartorow_numRows_0 = columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0].numRows();
/* 046 */       int columnartorow_localEnd_0 = columnartorow_numRows_0 - columnartorow_batchIdx_0;
/* 047 */       for (int columnartorow_localIdx_0 = 0; columnartorow_localIdx_0 < columnartorow_localEnd_0; columnartorow_localIdx_0++) {
/* 048 */         int columnartorow_rowIdx_0 = columnartorow_batchIdx_0 + columnartorow_localIdx_0;
/* 049 */         boolean project_isNull_0 = true;
/* 050 */         int project_value_0 = -1;
/* 051 */         boolean columnartorow_isNull_0 = columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2[0].isNullAt(columnartorow_rowIdx_0);
/* 052 */         int columnartorow_value_0 = columnartorow_isNull_0 ? -1 : (columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2[0].getInt(columnartorow_rowIdx_0));
/* 053 */         if (!columnartorow_isNull_0) {
/* 054 */           project_isNull_0 = false; // resultCode could change nullability.
/* 055 */
/* 056 */           project_value_0 = columnartorow_value_0 + 11;
/* 057 */
/* 058 */         }
/* 059 */         columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].reset();
/* 060 */
/* 061 */         columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].zeroOutNullBytes();
/* 062 */
/* 063 */         if (project_isNull_0) {
/* 064 */           columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].setNullAt(0);
/* 065 */         } else {
/* 066 */           columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].write(0, project_value_0);
/* 067 */         }
/* 068 */         append((columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].getRow()));
/* 069 */         if (shouldStop()) { columnartorow_batchIdx_0 = columnartorow_rowIdx_0 + 1; return; }
/* 070 */       }
/* 071 */       columnartorow_batchIdx_0 = columnartorow_numRows_0;
/* 072 */       columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] = null;
/* 073 */       columnartorow_nextBatch_0();
/* 074 */     }
/* 075 */   }
/* 076 */
/* 077 */ }
```

and for `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY()` the generated code is:

```
Generated code:
/* 001 */ public Object generate(Object[] references) {
/* 002 */   return new GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(references);
/* 003 */ }
/* 004 */
/* 005 */ // codegenStageId=1
/* 006 */ final class GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1 extends org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator {
/* 007 */   private Object[] references;
/* 008 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs;
/* 009 */   private int columnartorow_batchIdx_0;
/* 010 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2 = new org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector[1];
/* 011 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3 = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter[2];
/* 012 */   private org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1 = new org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch[1];
/* 013 */   private scala.collection.Iterator[] columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0 = new scala.collection.Iterator[1];
/* 014 */
/* 015 */   public GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1(Object[] references) {
/* 016 */     this.references = references;
/* 017 */   }
/* 018 */
/* 019 */   public void init(int index, scala.collection.Iterator[] inputs) {
/* 020 */     partitionIndex = index;
/* 021 */     this.inputs = inputs;
/* 022 */     columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0[0] = inputs[0];
/* 023 */
/* 024 */     columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[0] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 0);
/* 025 */     columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1] = new org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter(1, 0);
/* 026 */
/* 027 */   }
/* 028 */
/* 029 */   private void columnartorow_nextBatch_0() throws java.io.IOException {
/* 030 */     if (columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0[0].hasNext()) {
/* 031 */       columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] = (org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ColumnarBatch)columnartorow_mutableStateArray_0[0].next();
/* 032 */       ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[1] /* numInputBatches */).add(1);
/* 033 */       ((org.apache.spark.sql.execution.metric.SQLMetric) references[0] /* numOutputRows */).add(columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0].numRows());
/* 034 */       columnartorow_batchIdx_0 = 0;
/* 035 */       columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2[0] = (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.OnHeapColumnVector) columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0].column(0);
/* 036 */
/* 037 */     }
/* 038 */   }
/* 039 */
/* 040 */   protected void processNext() throws java.io.IOException {
/* 041 */     if (columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] == null) {
/* 042 */       columnartorow_nextBatch_0();
/* 043 */     }
/* 044 */     while ( columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] != null) {
/* 045 */       int columnartorow_numRows_0 = columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0].numRows();
/* 046 */       int columnartorow_localEnd_0 = columnartorow_numRows_0 - columnartorow_batchIdx_0;
/* 047 */       for (int columnartorow_localIdx_0 = 0; columnartorow_localIdx_0 < columnartorow_localEnd_0; columnartorow_localIdx_0++) {
/* 048 */         int columnartorow_rowIdx_0 = columnartorow_batchIdx_0 + columnartorow_localIdx_0;
/* 049 */         boolean project_isNull_0 = true;
/* 050 */         int project_value_0 = -1;
/* 051 */         boolean columnartorow_isNull_0 = columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2[0].isNullAt(columnartorow_rowIdx_0);
/* 052 */         int columnartorow_value_0 = columnartorow_isNull_0 ? -1 : (columnartorow_mutableStateArray_2[0].getInt(columnartorow_rowIdx_0));
/* 053 */         if (!columnartorow_isNull_0) {
/* 054 */           project_isNull_0 = false; // resultCode could change nullability.
/* 055 */
/* 056 */           project_value_0 = columnartorow_value_0 + 11;
/* 057 */
/* 058 */         }
/* 059 */         columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].reset();
/* 060 */
/* 061 */         columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].zeroOutNullBytes();
/* 062 */
/* 063 */         if (project_isNull_0) {
/* 064 */           columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].setNullAt(0);
/* 065 */         } else {
/* 066 */           columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].write(0, project_value_0);
/* 067 */         }
/* 068 */         append((columnartorow_mutableStateArray_3[1].getRow()));
/* 069 */         if (shouldStop()) { columnartorow_batchIdx_0 = columnartorow_rowIdx_0 + 1; return; }
/* 070 */       }
/* 071 */       columnartorow_batchIdx_0 = columnartorow_numRows_0;
/* 072 */       columnartorow_mutableStateArray_1[0] = null;
/* 073 */       columnartorow_nextBatch_0();
/* 074 */     }
/* 075 */   }
/* 076 */
/* 077 */ }
```

one thing I can't understand is what is actually serialized or de-serialized when we call `persist()` on dataframe? isn't dataframe serialized already?